# Bootstrap 3.3 Expand col-lg-10 to col-lg-12 at specific width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

This seems like it should be simple but my CSS/Responsive skills are not the best. I performed a cursory search on SO and didn't see anything that fit the bill of what I'm trying to accomplish.

My website has a basic 2 column layout - `col-lg-10` and `col-lg-2` inside a fluid container.

The `col-lg-2` div is a facebook-esque activity feed that I would like to collapse at or below a specific width. I've got this part working. The trick is that when the `col-lg-2` collapses I get a nice big gap on the right side of the screen where the `col-lg-2` used to be. I want the 'col-lg-10` to expand to take up the entire screen at this point instead of leaving the empty white space.

Real simple example at http://jsbin.com/meruci/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't use the same `min-width` as bootstrap does.

You use the `col-lg-*` class from bootstrap that take effect at `>=1200px` for the main-content.
But for your collapsed-part, you use your own media query that take effect at `>=1400px`...

So when the browser has a width of 1300px for example, your collapsed-part is not visible because the condition `>=1400px` return `false`, but the bootstrap takes already effect because the condition `>=1200` returns `true`...

To solve your problem, use the same min-width as bootstrap, so change your CSS from this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
```

to this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
```

**UPDATE :**

As example, try and improve this css :

```
    .has-border { border: 1px solid black; }

.main-content{
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px){
  .main-content{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 83.333%;

    float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  }
}
.collapsible { display: none; }
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .collapsible {

    display: block;
    width: 16.666%;
    margin: 0;
float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  } 
}
```

Comment: my problem is that at 1200px both primary content and the activity feed get too squished to really work at a desktop level. Is it feasible to alter the break-point for col-lg-* to 1400 and leave the rest as is?

Comment: Yes in that case you can create your own media query with a min-width of 1400px for the main content (like you did for the collapsable). And then use this new class, but not the bootstrap one to render your content. You can look at the bootstrap source to have an example of the media query

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try and report back with what happens.

Comment: no luck getting this working so far. Again I think it's my ignorance at media queries and Bootstrap in general. Feels like I might be close though. http://jsbin.com/meruci/2 it works right at 1200 like I want but between 1200 and 1400 it collapses down to a stacked layout which I don't want.

Comment: It's not exactly what I meant... Take a look at my updated answer above.